# Admob Banner Doesn't Showing Up

Tags: android, admob

I do everyting which need to show banner(with following Admob instuctors).

Banner is showing my `activity_main.xml` layout design. But It doesn't show up on devices(I try 5 mobile phones to see if banner is show up or not).

You can see my `activity_main.xml` layout design : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIz1u.png)

And you can see my app on google play(banner doesn't show up) = https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.be.app.a100interestingfacts

I also link my Admob to my Google Play.

My `MainActivity.java` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-2210729996978406~9750335544"); //I add this
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();//I add this
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);



    }
}
```

My `activity_main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F4FA58"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    .
    .
    .
    .

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView      //I add this
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2310839996878406/9126800798">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `build.gradle(project)` :

```
.
.
.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"  //I add this
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
.
```

My `build.gradle(Module)`:

```
    .
    .
    .
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0' //I add this

}
   . 
   .
   .
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new ad,Admob take time to deliver ad's.In that time you can test your ad using

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("D9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").build();
```

if test ad display your integration is perfect.

Comment: when you debug your app, open  you logcat and search addTestDevice.you will find your device ID.

Comment: addTestDevice("PUT_YOUR_DEVICE_ID_HERE")

Comment: is you add display?Full code.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("PUT_YOUR_DEVICE_ID_HERE").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: No, ad doesn't display but if I change unitID with sample unitID for Admob. It displays

Comment: now you check your xml. or create a empty project to try this code.

Comment: I create an empty project and add this codes but nothing change

Comment: There is no fault in your code. It's all good. You just need to wait a little

Comment: Any news on this one? You can use test banner ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" but I still can not see the ads :/